# beam join two streams with different windowing strategy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spark-streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, stream-processing

I have two independent streams of events , for one stream i have hourly buckets and for another stream i have 4 hour buckets , is it possible to join these two streams . How can i identify which windows on both stream to join ?
Can i have a sliding window on one stream and join this with a fixed window on another stream example use case is i partition one stream into fixed minutely/hourly buckets but want them to join with the 24 hour rolling/sliding bucket the windows have to be aligned with same start time .
Is it possible doing such in spark ?

Answer (score 1):

In dataflow, you can do what you are looking for using [Side Inputs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-inputs). Your first stream (an [unbounded PCollection](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pcollection#unbounded-pcollections)) will be the main input to a ParDo transform. Your second stream will be the side input. The latter will be of type [PCollectionView](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/values/PCollectionView), which is a way of representing a PCollection as a single entity and you can pass it to your ParDo transform by invoking .withSideInputs. Since your side input is infinite and thus cannot be compressed into a single value, the PCollectionView will represent a single entity per window.

[Regarding different window sizes](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-inputs-and-windowing), Dataflow projects the main input element's window into the side input's window set and then chooses the most appropriate side input window. In your example use case dataflow will project the main (hourly) input window against the side (24 hour) input window set and select the side input value from the appropriate 24 hour side input window.

Comment: Would a cogroupBy work by projecting one unbounded stream onto another ?

Comment: Also does it mean windows always start at fixed times i.e for example an hourly window 1-2 , 2-3 .. and not 1:10-2:10 , 2:10-3:10  ? Because if this is not the case how does projection works ? Also when side input is sliding window does it chooses multiple windows , for example if i have 2 hour 2-4 , 4-6 window and 24 hour sliding window every hour i.e 2-26, 3-27 .. , what projection is chosen for 2-4 ? is it 2-26 and 3-27 or just one window 2-26 ?